# nvd3.js tooltip date expression & refresh issue

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js, rickshaw

Currently, i'm developing realtime stackedAreaChart using nvd3.js.
nvd3.js is great, but i have two problem.

Example is following
http://jsfiddle.net/logo1318/1hkxfqhw/

**1. First Problem**

when i use following code

> ```
>      chart.xAxis
>        .tickFormat(function(d) {
>            return d3.time.format('%X')(new Date(d)); })
> ```

Tooltip shows "Nan:Nan:NaN" like following pic, but i want to show "12:33:33".
[image]

**2. Second Problem**

When i mouse over some position in chart, tooltip shows that position's content.

When chart is moving(updating) , tooltip doesn't show current position's content

But, until i move a mouse, tooltip content is not updating.

How can i update tooltip content like following examples in rickshaw.js?
http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/extensions.html

Thanks.